# google App Script: How to set a conditional rule in sending emails?

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently when a `Google form` is completed, an automated email is sent with the information that I choose. I need to update my function in order to make it sends me an email depending on which information is brought in my sheet (2 options possible). However, when I try, a syntax error appears.

This is my function :

```
function formSubmitReply(e) {

    var alUser = e.values[3];
    var entity = e.values[4];
    var language = e.values[2];
    var category = e.values[1];
    var title = e.values[5];
    var questions = e.values[6];
    var attach = e.values[7];

    var userEmail = "nicolas.medvedy@airliquide.com" + "," + "manuel.millan@airliquide.com";    

    var msg = "<p>MSG A</p>";  
              /*"<h4>AL user: </h4>" + alUser + 
              "<h4>Entity: </h4>" + entity + 
              "<h4>Preferred Language: </h4>" + language +
              "<h4>Category: </h4>" + category + 
              "<h4>Title: </h4>" + title + 
              "<h4>Question: </h4>" + questions + "<br>" +
              "<h4>Attachments: </h4>" + attach + "<br>";     */     

    var msgB = "<p> MSG B</p>";        
    
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: userEmail,
      subject: 'NAM HR Mailbox | ' + category,
      htmlBody:
      if (language == "Français") {
        return msg
        } else { 
          return msgB }  
          
    });
}
```

So, I need to set my conditional in order to change my msg variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to: userEmail,subject: 'NAM HR Mailbox | ' + category,htmlBody: (language=="Francais")?msg:msgB;
});
```

Comment: thank you very much!! I solved it..  anyway I have this doubt,  for example If I want to use if operator is it possible?

Comment: The problem with your statement is the return because it terminates the function.

Comment: This could also be translated with the ```if``` statement to ```MailApp.sendEmail({to: userEmail,subject: 'NAM HR Mailbox | ' + category,htmlBody: if(language=="Francais"){msg}else{msgB};});```. As @Cooper mentioned just remove the ```return``` as this will terminate your function and therefore you wont be able to send the message.